# Outputting multiple variables defined in a method

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, variables, methods

I have series of basic calculations on a form triggered by the form load event:

```
Dim someVariableA As Integer
Dim someVariableB As Integer
Dim someVariableX As Integer = 1
Dim someVariableY As Integer = 2 

someVariableA = someVariableX + someVariableY
someVariableB = someVariableX * someVariableY
```

I now require the exact calculations for a separate form. Rather than pasting the same again, is there a means by which I can place the calculation in a method that both forms can call upon?

```
Public Function someFunction()
    ' Above calculations placed here instead.
End Function

Private Sub someSub()
    ' Call calculations.
    someFunction()
    ' ...now output and use variables from function.
    TextBox1.Text = someVariableA
    TextBox2.Text = someVariableB
End Sub
```

Ultimately, I'm expecting something that behaves like PHP's include function.

Comment: yes you can do this, add Module to your project and define the function there, then you can call the function as YourModule.someFunction, hope it will help you

Comment: Yes, thats the basics of OOP, all processing/functions should be placed in a class, where all forms can access it.

Comment: @HadiHassan I've followed your instructions however my variable is still being marked as undeclared. I've called `someModule.someFunction()` but when I attempt to output a variable defined in the function: `TextBox1.Text = someVariableA` ... I'm told that `someVariableA` is undeclared.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK Cheers for the explanation however the variables within the function aren't declared even after I call the method.

Comment: the variables should be public properties in the Module to work

Comment: or you can encapsulate these variables inside a class let us call it Result with 4 properties A,B,X and Y then the function will return the result and you can access it as result.A or result.B, i can make a sample code if you want

Comment: You can: Make a separate function for each calculation; Create a new class with both variables and return a single object of that class; Make those two variables public and a `Sub` to manipulate them; Create one function and pass values `ByRef`. You should implement one of the first two options, they make the code "cleaner" and avoid the last two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the issue of [Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx).  Where a variable is declared determines its availability.  You probably know how to make variables visible to all methods in a form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private varA As String
    Private var2 As Integer
```

These will be available to all methods in the form because the are declared at the Form level (unlike a variable declared (`Dim`) inside a procedure which will exist only locally).  To make them visible to all methods in the app's forms, declare them in a module:

```
Public Module1
    Friend varA As String
    Friend var2 As Integer
    Friend varX As DateTime
```

Declared in a module (1980s style!), they become global variables for your app. But there is **good reason to avoid this**.  It is so easy to change a value, you can have methods which accidentally or unwittingly do so - remember they are now visible to everything even those procedure which might have no good reason to change them!  Then, you spend time trying to locate those methods which are changing the value(s) but should not be.

A gigantic benefit of OOP is the ability to avoid this by using classes to hold the data *and* contain methods to manage that data - they can do everything from loading and saving to the calcualations you need.   A sign that this might be what you need is that you have some *variables you want to be global* and already have *methods which are global*,  combine them and you have a class:

```
Public Class Foo
    Private varA As String
    Private var2 As Integer

    ' some of these things might be better as Properties
    ' this allows the subscribers (users of the class) to change the
    ' values directly:
    Public Property SomeDate As DateTime
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Integer

    Public Function GetSomething(aVar As Integer) As Integer
       var2 += aVar         ' update var2 for example
       Return var2          ' return new value
    End Function
```

To make the class available to all forms:

```
Public Module1
    Friend myFoo As Foo            ' makes it visible to all forms
```

Then create an instance of your class from your main form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form_Load(....
       myFoo = new Foo
```

Now, `myFoo` is an instance of the `Foo` class which not only houses those variables, but the methods to manage them:

```
Private Sub button_click(....
     someVar = myFoo.DoSomething(42)
```

Comment: I dont quite follow, but the actions in a method might return a value (making it a function) but *also* change some of the other variable values as well.  So you might have `If myFoo.someFunc() Then tbSomething.Text = myFoo.Name`  where "Name" is one of the properties you've defined to expose certain values

Comment: This works. Thanks for the robust answer and education. I didn't realise the module approach was considered so outdated. Thanks.

Comment: equally greasy is passing ByRef...it makes it difficult to know at a glance that param might change.  Just do the same thing - change vars which are tied to Props and get those values that way

Comment: Regarding `create an instance of your class from your main form:`, does this mean **only** my main form (i.e. the first form that's presented) or does it mean **any** form I wish to use the class on?

Comment: Note that `myFoo` is **declared** in the module - that makes it visible to everything.  the main form just creates the instance

Comment: Sorry to drag this out but to simplify, I have 1 function that defines values for 20 variables. I want to call that function which results in the variables being declared in my form. I can achieve this a module `(SomeModule.someFunction()` then       `MessageBox.Show(someVariable))`. I cannot reproduce this with the class approach `((SomeClass.someFunction()` then       `MessageBox.Show(someVariable))`. I want to call the values in one function rather than creating a function per each required variable (just like PHP include).

Comment: a bit abstract, but a class can be more powerful than a form or module approach.  It might be *how* you are trying to do it: `If myFoo.someFunc(aVar) Then MessageBox.Show(myFoo.SomeProperty)`